# A glass prism and a polaroid photo film

Tags: glass

Let's say I am in a very dark room and a have a lamp with a cardboard tube around it. The cardboard tube has a tiny hole so light can leave. If a place a glass prism in the way of the beam, would I get a spectral image on the photographic polaroid film? Of course, I would place the film so that the "rainbow" lies directly on the film. If so, would it appear in a timeframe of minutes or rather hours?

Comment: Re "...timeframe..." Depends on how bright the light, on how big the aperture, and on how sensitive the film.

Answer (score 0):

You would, and it would appear in less than a second unless the light hole was very very tiny.

Comment: oh wow! Nice! I will give it a go soon, thanks